# Rails 4 simple Quiz web app using Cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

My current task is to create simple Quiz web app. App will be structured this way: 
 - Admin can create, edit, delete and activate quizzes.
 - Visitors can take a quiz and submit it. Then receiving quiz results etc.

So far I have created nested form (with [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem) where admin can create quiz's and add new questions and possible answers, but I have not a single idea how to make that nested form as submit-able quiz for visitors.

My code:

Form:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @test] do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>

  <h3>Questions</h3>


  <div id="question">
    <%= f.fields_for :questions do |question| %>
      <%= render 'admin/question_fields', f: question %>
    <% end %>


    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add question', f, :questions %>
    </div>


  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**_question_fields partial:**

```
<div class="nested-fields">

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>

  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove question", f %>


  <h3>Answers</h3>
  <div id="answers">
    <%= f.fields_for :answers do |answer| %>
      <%= render 'admin/answer_fields', f: answer %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add answer', f, :answers %>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

**Question**: What is the best way to allow dynamic nested form to be used for taking tests by visitors and store submitted data in database?

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: I don't understand the question. You make a POST request to save user's answers in the database?

Comment: @myfashionhub  , I don't have any code for user answers. I shared code thus far for creating nested forms as suggested for quizzes and tests etc.

Comment: The users will submit their answers to the questions in a form and their answers results will be saved to the database. The form does not need to be nested.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss , Thanks, can u share a bit of code how that should look like ? I have no idea how to do that..

Comment: Please look at some tutorials. You shouldn't be asking a question on SO without having code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark

Comment: Just give each test an id and each question on the test an id. Then save the form with all the answers and test the answers for correctness.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss , That form I shared above is just for creating dynamic tests from admin panel. If user had access to that form he could edit/create tests but NOT submit test with answers. I am kinda searching for way to duplicate that exact form for visitors so the only input they could do is click on their preffered answer checkbox and then submit.

Comment: Create a new form populated by the test model

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss  , Thanks for tip !

Comment: @edjars did you get all of this running how you wanted?

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss  Thanks. Yes, i got everything working .